# Laravel problem loading assets 400 bad request

Tags: laravel, apache, vhosts

I have a Laravel website that work perfectly on localhost but when i deploy that, there is a problem with loading assets or other files **from public directory**.

> Bad Request
>   Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

It's my apache vHost :

```
<VirtualHost IP:8181>
    ServerName my-domain.com
    ServerAlias www.my-domain.com
    ServerAdmin info@my-domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/laravel/public
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/user/public_html/cgi-bin/

    ErrorLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/my-domain.com.error.log

    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "^https$" HTTPS=on
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir disabled
        UserDir enabled user
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
        SuexecUserGroup user user
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup user user
        suPHP_ConfigPath /home/user
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid user user
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule itk.c>
        AssignUserID user user
    </IfModule>

    <Directory "/home/user/public_html">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And it's apache log :

> Invalid URI in request GET \@backend HTTP/1.0

There is many laravel sites and all of them are normal but i have problem with this one. I can't figure out this problem.
My `vHost.conf` is OK, my `.env` files is OK, but i can't load any assets such as css / js / robots.txt / etc ... **( anything that saved in public directory )**.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: What's the permission set for assets directory?

Comment: It's 755. CWP manage permissions automatically @Iftikharuddin

Comment: I don't think the issue is missing files or wrong paths. You would get 440, or 500. The 400 error indicates mal formed request. Your request **\@backend** looks odd. There is a backslash \ and a @ in this URI. This might work in some tests on Windows locally, but are you sure the hosted website allows it ? Have you tried to encode the backslash, like GET %5C@backend ?

Answer (score 0):

I think changing

```
<Directory "/home/user/public_html">
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory "/home/user/public_html/laravel/public">
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

might help ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your document root to `/home/user/public_html`.